# How to retrieve values from normalised database structure without multiple joins?

Tags: mysql

I have the folowing db shema (MySQL 5.x) where I save values of items inside one table and the corresponding names of each attribute in another one:

classified_attr (attributes belonging to specific classified)

```
cl_id | value
39393 | 173
```

cat_attr (attribute names):

```
attr_id | attr_de
173       green
123       available
```

This works for all cases I need except one, where I am facing some performance issues since I need to retrieve with one SQL query all of the values from one item including the names.

I am doing this by joinging tables multiple times for each value. e.g.

```
SELECT 
    ca_power.value AS power_id,
    catr_power.attr_de AS power,   
    ca_avail.value AS avail_id,  
    catr_avail.attr_de AS avail                              
FROM
    classifieds AS c
LEFT JOIN classifieds_attr AS ca_power ON c.ID = ca_power.cl_id AND ca_power.attr_group_id = 19
LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_power ON ca_power.attr_group_id = ca_power.attr_group_id AND catr_power.attr_id =  ca_power.value
LEFT JOIN classifieds_attr AS ca_avail ON c.ID = ca_avail.cl_id AND ca_avail.attr_group_id = 17
LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr_avail ON ca_avail.attr_group_id = ca_avail.attr_group_id AND catr_avail.attr_id =  ca_avail.value
```

For those two attributes and their names it is neglactable, but now there are over 10 attributes and I am facing a performance degration.

Is there a way to alter my SQL query in order to retrieve all those values including name in a faster way, while keeping the structure? And if not, what would be a better aproach to storing those values?

Comment: What indexes do your tables (`classifieds_attr` and `cat_attr`) have?

Comment: They have an index on each column.

Comment: The second `LEFT JOIN` has a redundant condition: `ca_power.attr_group_id = ca_power.attr_group_id`. Maybe you should remove it.

Comment: The fourth `LEFT JOIN` also has a redundant condition. Are you sure this query is allright?

Answer (score 1):

Ok your query is a bit odd as you are self joining the `classifieds_attr` table to itself multiple times (`ca_power.attr_group_id = ca_power.attr_group_id` and `ca_avail.attr_group_id = ca_avail.attr_group_id`) which is totally unnecessary, especially as it's done as part of the join condition to the `cat_attr` table.

Additionally your multiple joins to the `classifieds_attr` and `cat_attr` tables appear to only differ by the attr_group_id column (not present in your spec above).

You can simplify your query by dropping the redundant joins and turning it into a pivot query:

```
SELECT 
    c.id as classified_id,
    -- Power Group (19)
    max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 19 then ca.value end) AS power_id,
    max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 19 then catr.attr_de end) AS power,
    -- Avail Group (17)
    max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 17 then ca.value end) AS avail_id,
    max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 17 then catr.attr_de end) AS avail
FROM
    classifieds AS c
LEFT JOIN classifieds_attr AS ca
  ON c.ID = ca.cl_id
 AND ca.attr_group_id in (17,19)
LEFT JOIN cat_attr AS catr
  ON catr.attr_id =  ca.value
GROUP BY c.id
```

To add additional columns (groups) simply duplicate the aggregate columns (note the commented columns above) changing the group id in the case statement and add the appropriate group id to the in list of the first join.

You could also try inner joining `cat_attr` to `classifieds_attr` assuming that `ca.value` is a required field and is a foreign key to `cat_attr` referencing `attr_id`.  You didn't supply much meta data so it's hard to know your setup. Anyway here's that potential optimization:

```
SELECT c.id as classified_id,
    -- Power Group (19)
       max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 19 then ca.value end) AS power_id,
       max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 19 then catr.attr_de end) AS power,
    -- Avail Group (17)
       max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 17 then ca.value end) AS avail_id,
       max(case when ca.attr_group_id = 17 then catr.attr_de end) AS avail
  FROM classifieds AS c
  LEFT JOIN classifieds_attr AS ca
       JOIN cat_attr AS catr
         ON catr.attr_id =  ca.value
    ON c.ID = ca.cl_id
   AND ca.attr_group_id in (17,19)
 GROUP BY c.id
```

If you don't care about seeing `classified.id`s that have no attributes, then you can also switch the first join from an outer join to an inner join and possibly gain some additional performance.

Comment: The self joining was a good hint, removed. Query takes 1.6s which might be OK, since it is the dataimport query for solr and only executed once. The attr_group_id is the attribute I am trying to pull in. e.g. color of the item. Do you believe I will see a performance increae after rewriting the query as a pivot query?

Comment: Quite likely, since you will only need to access each table once instead of once for each group, additionally if you can eliminate any or all of the outer joins that will help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following indexes (if you don't already have them):

```
create index ix1 on classifieds_attr (cl_id, attr_group_id);

create index ix2 on cat_attr (attr_id);
```

This should speed up your query considerable. Nevertheless, there's something fishy on your query since it has two redundant, useless filtering conditions.

You seem to have multiple single-column indexes. However, the first one -- the composite index -- is critical for the performance.

Comment: The self joining was a good hint, removed. Query takes 1.6s which might be OK, since it is the dataimport query for solr and only executed once. The indexes are all set.